# PInterest - How To Verify Your Website

Tags: html, header, meta-tags

Pinterest wants me to Verify my Website so it can be recognized as a business Pinterest page. Where in Magento do I find the html.index file to add the meta tag?

Comment: in `template/pages/html/head.phtml` I guess

Comment: Please take your time to accept an anser it it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

From the official [pintrest website](https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/verify-your-website) it appears that you can do one of two things.

**Upload a file to the root dir**

Uploading the file is probably the easiest way as it does not involve any code. Simply using ftp or how ever you upload files to your server copy the file provided by pintrest across to your sever in a similar way to google webmasters tool.

**Add a meta tag**

This is the more "complex" way as it will involve some coding, which I assume you are happy to do. What you can do is create a local.xml file in your theme, or use any other layout xml file. Use the `default` node so that it happens on every page and the following snippet.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="blockname">
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[<meta your-meta-tag-information-goes-here/>]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

As I said for me the file approach would be "easier" but both should work.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change files for that. In your admin panel, go to `System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head` and add your meta tag to the text area `Miscellaneous Scripts`

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't have a index.html file, I'm sure you can verify pinterest by uploading a file to your root, you would be better doing it this way